# Django How to save same model form twice on one submit request

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views, django-forms

I'm a newbie to Django and I'm trying to save a single Model Form twice in my views.py since I want to create two distinct rows in the DB. I am able to save the forms and create two rows in the DB, but unfortunately the values from the second form get saved in both my rows. 
I want to save two distinct rows for the same Model on clicking the submit button once.

I have gone through the posts - [django submit two different forms with one submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489393/django-submit-two-different-forms-with-one-submit-button) and [Django: saving multiple modelforms simultaneously (complex case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033121/django-saving-multiple-modelforms-simultaneously-complex-case) , but it did not answer my query, since I want to save the SAME Model Form twice.

Following is my function for saving the Form:

```
@csrf_protect
@login_required
@never_cache  
def testQuotaReq(request):
    form1 = quotaRequestForm(request.POST or None)
    form2 = quotaRequestForm(request.POST or None)

if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():        
    form1.process()
    save1 = form1.save(commit=True)
    save1.save()    

    form2.process()
    save2 = form2.save(commit=True)
    save2.save()

    return HttpResponse("Form1 Form2 saved")
        #else:
        #    return HttpResponse('Thanks for your request! Your request id is: %d .' % (save1.pk) )  
else:
    form1 = quotaRequestForm()
    form2 = quotaRequestForm()

return render_to_response('quotaRequest.html',
                              locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This above piece of code creates the following rows in the table (simplified to highlight issue):

```
Id  Descr   Val CPU RAM     Inst

76  testing 18  180 18432   18  
75  testing 18  180 18432   18  
74  testing 11  110 11264   11  
73  testing 11  110 11264   11
```

Over here, the values received from HTML for row 75 and 76 are different. Similarly for 73 and 74. Am I missing something ? Appreciate your help!

Edit:

HTML Code:

```
<form method='POST' action='' id="formSubmit"> {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form1">
    {{ form1.as_p }}
    </div>

    <div class="form2">  
    {{ form2.as_p }}
    </div>

    <a class="btn btn-info" href="/quotaRequest">Cancel Request</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><b>Submit Request</b></button>
    </form>
```

Also, I edited the function in views.py as below, but I'm still not able to add two distinct rows in the DB for the same modelForm. I am unclear how to use the prefix tag. Help appreciated!

```
@csrf_protect
@login_required
@never_cache  
def testQuotaReq(request):
    form1 = quotaRequestForm(request.POST or None, prefix="form-1")
    form2 = quotaRequestForm(request.POST or None, prefix="form-2")

    if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():        
        form1.process()
        save1 = form1.save(commit=True)
        save1.save()    

        form2.process()
        save2 = form2.save(commit=True)
        save2.save()

        return HttpResponse("Form1 Form2 saved")
#     else:
#         form1 = quotaRequestForm()
#         form2 = quotaRequestForm()
    return render_to_response('quotaRequest.html',locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your two forms generate `input` elements with the same names, so the data for the last input gets posted for both forms.

You can specify two unique `prefix`es to differentiate between the forms:

```
form1 = quotaRequestForm(request.POST or None, prefix='form-1')
form2 = quotaRequestForm(request.POST or None, prefix='form-2')
```

You need to specify the correct `prefix` every time you instantiate the form.

Btw, you might want to remove the `else` clause. Currently, if either form is not valid, the data gets wiped. If you do not reset the values, the form gets displayed with the input from the first submit and with correct error messages to the user.

Comment: Hi @knbk thanks for your prompt response. However, I am unable to get the issue solved by using prefix tag. Infact now, nothing is getting committed to the DB. I am editing my code above, so that hopefully you can point me in the right direction. I am not very clear how to make use of the prefix tag to distinguish my model forms.

Comment: Hello @knbk , your solution worked! Somehow the prefix was not getting added to my input elements in HTML, but everything worked fine when I restarted my server and I am now able to insert two distinct rows for the same modelform in my DB. Thanks a lot for your help! Really appreciate it !